# Access object within event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

How can I access object foo? I want to pass it to the event listener. Do I have to make foo global?

```
function test(){
  var foo = {
    bar:2
  }
}
$('#bla').on('click',function(){
  foo.bar = 5;
});
```

Comment: You can't. `foo` is only available within the scope of `test` in the example code.

Comment: Does it mean I have to make any object I want to use in an event listener global or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: It doesn't need to be global, just within scope of all locations you want to use it. I'd suggest creating your own namespace and working within that.

Comment: @user3024814 You could wrap the function `test` and the event listener inside an IIFE and make the object `foo` outside of both but inside the IIFE. That way `foo` won't be global

Answer (score 1):

**Try Following**

```js
var foo={};
test();
function test(){
  foo.bar=2  ;
}
$('#bla').on('click',function(){
  foo.bar = 5;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="test" id="bla"/>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make it a global variable / add it to window object?